# Create "geometry" data type using migrations?

Tags: postgresql, laravel

Text is easy to do:

```
$table->text('description');
```

But how would you do one for postgres, that would ultimately give you a column of type "geometry"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As you can see](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns), there is no column type `geometry` in built-in column type list. So use custom SQL in migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddGeometryColumnToMyTable extends Migration 
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point,4326);');
    }

    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE some_table DROP COLUMN geom RESTRICT;');
    }
}
```